# Choosing the image on which the baking goes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

The problem I have is really simple: even though I select one image in the UV Editor window, when I try to bake the render results on it he overwrites another one (which is one of the textures I use) with the baking results. Perhaps this is due to using the Material Nodes in Cycles, which I'm using since a short time.
How can I choose the image on which to Bake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the method I use:

1. Create a new Texture in the UV/Image Editor and name it appropriately.
2. Create a new Image Texture node in the Node Editor (no connection to the tree) and select your created Image in the dropdown menu.
3. With this new texture node selected, go to yo Render Panel and bake your texture.
4. Repeat from Step 1 for different Bake Types.

[image: cycles bake to texture]

Comment: I see, that's because as @ray-mairlot says it bakes on the selected node. Thanks guys!

Comment: How do you do this in Blender 2.8?

Comment: @HugoZink You can use the same process in 2.8, just make sure the "Clear Image" checkbox is unchecked if you're doing multiple bakes.

Answer (score 2):

Cycles doesn't use the image in the UV Image Editor as the 'baking target', it uses the selected image node in the Node Editor. So, on the material for the object you are baking, add a new image node and add a blank image for it to use (this will be where the baked result goes), make sure the new node is selected and then bake.

The new image node doesn't have to be connected to anything for the baking to work and can be deleted afterwards. Admittedly, it's a bit of a strange workflow, to have to add a new node just for this, but that's the way it is at the moment.